# MUI: How to manually change tabindex of Dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the tabindex of MUI Dialog.

When I use Dialog, I see this html tag is generated.

```
<div class="MuiDialog-container MuiDialog-scrollPaper" role="none presentation" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;">
  // Children
</div>
```

In the parent div wrapper, the -1 is set to tabindex and I would like to change this value. I'm using react.js and MUI version 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dialog component is using a div tag for the presentation role at root level just under body (with MuiDialog-root class) and another div inside with MuiDialog-container and MuiDialog-scrollPaper classes (which are the ones you want to change).

You can change either of them using Dialog props:

```
<Dialog open={open} tabIndex={4} PaperProps={{ tabIndex: 4 }}>
```

- tabIndex prop will be used for the parent div and the one inside PaperProps is the one you are asking for which changes tabindex on the child div element.

For more info, you can look in the Material UI docs.

Here's a [demo](https://v4.mui.com/components/dialogs/) of the dialog component.

And the docs for the [MUI version 4 Dialog API](https://v4.mui.com/components/dialogs), where you can find the PaperProps prop.

Comment: Can you share a link to where you can find out more info in the MUI docs?

Comment: Sure. You can check here: https://v4.mui.com/components/dialogs/ (for MUI version 4 Dialog demos) and here https://v4.mui.com/api/dialog/ (for MUI version 4 Dialog API, where you can find the PaperProps prop)

Comment: @cris_b, I edited your post to include the links to the docs. This should help the OP answer these sorts of questions for themselves next time.

Comment: @crls_b Thank you for the info. You saved me a lot but I think to edit the html attribute of the root level of the Dialog component, I had to use `TransitionProps`. That's all I had to change from your sample code.